# Change default Continue (F8) Step Into(F11) Step Over(F10) in Firebug

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firebug

Can one change these shortcuts to something else and where in that case?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a feature request for this (you need a GoogleGroups account to access):
[F5 vs F8 for continue Options](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/8329a1a23314a61a?pli=1)
There was also a workaround done for earlier versions of FireFox by Patrick Kaeding, but from what I can work out, it doesn't work with the current version (FireFox 3.6, FireBug 1.5) 
[Customize Firebug shortcut keys](http://kaeding.name/articles/2008/12/11/customize-firebug-shortcut-keys/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is too old but I hope my answer will help somebody.

Firefox extension is usual zip-archive. If you unarchive it u can edit file: `"${Firebug_unarchived}/content/firebug/js/scriptPanel.js"`.
In this file find lines #**919 - 929** with content:

```
Firebug.chrome.$("fbRerunButton").setAttribute("tooltiptext",
        Locale.$STRF("firebug.labelWithShortcut", [Locale.$STR("script.Rerun"), "Shift+F8"]));
Firebug.chrome.$("fbContinueButton").setAttribute("tooltiptext",
        Locale.$STRF("firebug.labelWithShortcut", [Locale.$STR("script.Continue"), "F8"]));
Firebug.chrome.$("fbStepIntoButton").setAttribute("tooltiptext",
        Locale.$STRF("firebug.labelWithShortcut", [Locale.$STR("script.Step_Into"), "F11"]));
Firebug.chrome.$("fbStepOverButton").setAttribute("tooltiptext",
        Locale.$STRF("firebug.labelWithShortcut", [Locale.$STR("script.Step_Over"), "F10"]));
Firebug.chrome.$("fbStepOutButton").setAttribute("tooltiptext",
        Locale.$STRF("firebug.labelWithShortcut",
            [Locale.$STR("script.Step_Out"), "Shift+F11"]));
```

There are hotkeys for debugger commands. Simply changed it and package extension back.

**Be careful** after firebug update all hotkeys will reset so you should change them again (or simply disable auto-update for `Firebug`).

P.S. Actual version of `Firebug` is 1.11.4.